# Maximum value of function involving factorials

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, factorial

Define $$g_{(k,j)} = \frac{a^{n-k}b^k(k+n)!x^{k+n-j}}{k!(n-k)!(k+n-j)!}$$, where $n,k,j \in \Bbb{N}$  are fixed such that $(0 \leq x \leq a/b ),(b<a),(0 \leq k \leq n ),(2 \leq j \leq 2n),(0 \leq k+n-j)$.

By the continuity of $g_{(k,j)}$ in compact $[0,a/b]$, there exists $x_{(k,j)} \in [0,a/b]$ that is the maximum of $g_{(k,j)}(x)$.

Define $A = \{(k,j) : (0 \leq k \leq n) and (2 \leq j \leq 2n)\}$ that is finite, so there exists $x_{m} \in [0,a/b]$, and $(k_{m},j_{m})$ such that

$g_{(k_{m},j_{m})} (x_{m}) = max_{(k,j) \in A}\{g_{(k,j)}(x_{(k,j)}): x_{(k,j)}$ is the maximum of $g_{(k,j)}(x)\}$

We are interested in find $(k,j,x)$ that is $g_{(k_{m},j_{m})} (x_{m})$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is maximized when $x$ is as large as possible, so $x=a/b$.

The ratio $g(k,j+1)/g(k,j)=(b/a)(k+n-j)$.  So long as the ratio is more than 1, $g(k,j)$ is increasing with $j$, but when the ratio dips below 1, $g(k,j)$ starts decreasing. so it is maximized when $j=k+n-a/b$ - or else at an endpoint $j=2$ or $j=k+n$

Comment: Hi, Michael. So we have $(k,j,x) = (k,k+n-a/b,a/b)$, or $(k,j,x) = (k,2,a/b)$ or $(k,j,x) = (k,k+n,a/b)$. But about $k$?

Comment: Look at the ratio for $k$ as well.  I think the ratio there is $(k+n+1)(n-k)/((k+1)(k+n+1-j))$, and again you set that equal to 1.

Comment: @user163874, I think after all the question of $k$ is trickier than that because $j$ is now a function of $k$.  Perhaps calculate all values of $k$ and choose the biggest.

Comment: It's true. I'll try in this way. Thank you. I forgot to say that $n,k,j \in \Bbb{N}$.

Comment: In $(k+n+1)(n-k)/((k+1)(k+n+1-j))$.  
For $(k_{1},j,x)=(k_{1},2,a/b)$,$j=2$, and setting that equal to 1, I found $k_{1}=\frac{n}{2}$, so $k_{1}\in\{0,n/2,n\}$. For $(k_{2},j,x)=(k_{2},k_{2}+n,a/b)$,and setting that equal to 1, I found $k_{2}=n−1$, so $k_{2}\in\{0,n−1,n\}$. Putting $a/b≈1$, for $(k_{3},k_{3}+n−a/b,a/b)$,and setting that equal to 1, I found $k_{3}=n−1$, so $k_{3}\in\{0,n−1,n\}$